como usar Case WHEN en sql server?
Buenas quisiera que me guiaran,tengo que usar Case When por temas de eficiencia segun me corregieron en mi trabajo, tengo esta tabla

esta es mi tabla, dejo la tabla ejemplo para tener los datos disponibles que estoy intentado hacer
create table cart
(
idcart int primary key,
cic varchar(100),
fecha varchar(100),
cliente varchar(100),
saldo decimal
)

select * from cart

insert into cart values (1,'89211','202002','Cristhian',100)
insert into cart values (2,'89211','202002','Cristhian',3000)
insert into cart values (3,'89211','202002','Cristhian',3000)
insert into cart values (4,'89211','202002','Cristhian',4000)

insert into cart values (5,'89211','202003','Cristhian',2000)
insert into cart values (6,'89211','202004','Cristhian',1000)
insert into cart values (7,'89211','202005','Cristhian',3000)
insert into cart values (8,'89211','202006','Cristhian',6000)
insert into cart values (9,'89211','202007','Cristhian',3000)
insert into cart values (10,'89211','202008','Cristhian',6000)
insert into cart values (11,'89211','202009','Cristhian',2000)
insert into cart values (12,'89211','202010','Cristhian',1500)
insert into cart values (13,'89211','202011','Cristhian',1900)
insert into cart values (14,'89211','202012','Cristhian',2400)
insert into cart values (15,'89211','202101','Cristhian',5600)


insert into cart values (16,'23244','202003','pepe',2000)
insert into cart values (17,'23244','202004','pepe',1000)
insert into cart values (18,'23244','202005','pepe',3000)
insert into cart values (19,'23244','202006','pepe',6000)
insert into cart values (20,'23244','202007','pepe',3000)
insert into cart values (21,'23244','202008','pepe',6000)
insert into cart values (22,'23244','202009','pepe',2000)
insert into cart values (23,'23244','202010','pepe',1500)
insert into cart values (24,'23244','202011','pepe',1900)
insert into cart values (25,'23244','202012','pepe',2400)

lo que hice primero fue añadir el row_num para poder enumerar por cic(DNI)
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblsaldo2') is not null drop table #tblsaldo2 
SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CIC ORDER BY Mes desc) AS row_num,
   CIC,
   Mes,
   saldo INTO #tblsaldo2  
FROM  #tblsaldo

y despues use esta consulta para poder calcular los saldos de 24meses, 12meses, 6meses y 3 meses
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblsaldo3') is not null drop table #tblsaldo3
select T1.CIC,T5.MesActual,T4.Mes24,T3.Mes12,T2.Mes6,T1.Mes3
  INTO #tblsaldo3
  from  
 (  select  CIC,avg(saldo)as Mes3 from #tblsaldo2
WHERE row_num BETWEEN 1 AND 3
  group by CIC
) T1
left join
 ( select  CIC,avg(saldo)as Mes6 from #tblsaldo2
WHERE row_num BETWEEN 1 AND 6
  group by CIC
) T2 on T1.CIC = T2.CIC
left join
 ( select  CIC,avg(saldo)as Mes12 from #tblsaldo2
WHERE row_num BETWEEN 1 AND 12
  group by CIC
) T3 on T1.CIC = T3.CIC
left join
 ( select  CIC,avg(saldo)as Mes24 from #tblsaldo2
WHERE row_num BETWEEN 1 AND 24
  group by CIC
) T4 on T1.CIC = T4.CIC
left join
 ( select CIC,saldo as MesActual from #tblsaldo2
WHERE row_num like 1
) T5 on T1.CIC = T5.CIC

ahora quisiera hacer lo mismo, pero usando CASE WHEN, pero no estoy pudiendo llegar al resultado, tengo esto
select row_num,cic, avg(saldo) as nro6meses,
CASE 
    WHEN row_num BETWEEN 1 AND 6  THEN '6meses'
    ELSE 'NOTHING'
END AS '6meses'

FROM #tblsaldo2
--where row_num BETWEEN 1 AND 6 
-- and  row_num BETWEEN 1 AND 3 
group by row_num,cic

y sale esto

tengo que llegar a esto


¿Qué es el número que va en cada columna de 24, 12, 6 y 3 meses? ¿de dónde sale o como se calcula?

Ah, y por favor, publica los datos de la tabla como texto, no como imagen, de esa forma se simplifica escribir una respuesta usando dichos datos.

@jachguate los 24,12,6 y 3 sale de la consulta ( select  CIC,avg(saldo)as Mes12 from #tblsaldo2
WHERE row_num BETWEEN 1 AND 12
group by CIC
) y bueno quisiera colocar los datos de la tabla, pero es que en realidad son miles de registros y no podria colocar todos

no coloques toda la tabla, pero la misma porción que se ve en la imagen, y los resultados que esperas obtener exactamente con esos datos, es de ayuda para quien quiera ayudarte. :)

@jachguate gracias ya puse los datos de la tabla con sus inserts, como dije quiero sacar un promedio de dichos meses

Tu consulta tiene el problema de que si hace falta un mes, los datos se recorrerían. También espera que solo haya una fila por mes y CIC.
Tampoco es necesario estar creando tablas temporales. Cada creación de una tabla temporal implica que tienes que escribir y luego leer los datos. Eso puede llegar a ser costoso si abusamos de ello.
Podemos hacerlo de una forma más sencilla con un poco de cálculo de fechas.
DECLARE @Fecha  date = '20210101';

SELECT CIC,
    AVG( CASE WHEN fecha = CONVERT( CHAR(6), @Fecha, 112) THEN saldo END) AS MesActual,
    AVG( saldo) AS [24Meses],
    AVG( CASE WHEN fecha BETWEEN CONVERT( CHAR(6), DATEADD( MM, -11, @Fecha), 112) AND CONVERT( CHAR(6), @Fecha, 112) THEN saldo END) AS [12Meses],
    AVG( CASE WHEN fecha BETWEEN CONVERT( CHAR(6), DATEADD( MM,  -5, @Fecha), 112) AND CONVERT( CHAR(6), @Fecha, 112) THEN saldo END) AS [6Meses],
    AVG( CASE WHEN fecha BETWEEN CONVERT( CHAR(6), DATEADD( MM,  -2, @Fecha), 112) AND CONVERT( CHAR(6), @Fecha, 112) THEN saldo END) AS [3Meses]
FROM cart
WHERE fecha BETWEEN CONVERT( CHAR(6), DATEADD( MM, -23, @Fecha), 112) AND CONVERT( CHAR(6), @Fecha, 112)
GROUP BY CIC;


Hola, @Luis Cazares, tu respuesta es lo que más se aproxima...tengo otra consulta si me podrías ayudar. .si ya converti la fecha con un convert y ya no necesito declararla como variable como tendría que hacerlo? Eh intentado y no me refleja.. aunque al final creo que usaré tu ejemplo

Quieras aplicar una agregación condicional.
select 
  cic,
  avg(case when row_num between 1 and  3 then saldo end) as nro3meses,
  avg(case when row_num between 1 and  6 then saldo end) as nro6meses,
  avg(case when row_num between 1 and 12 then saldo end) as nro12meses
from #tblsaldo2
group by cic
order by cic;

Si quieres tener la palabra 'NOTHING' en vez de null, sería lo mejor hacer lo en tu programa que muestra los datos (una app, una página de web), no en SQL.
Si quieres hacerlo en SQL, tienes que cambiar tus resultados a strings (VARCHAR), porque 'NOTHING' es un string. Para convertir los números en strings, tienes que decidir cómo hacerlo. Por ejemplo, el número 1234.56 se puede mostrar como '1234.56' o '1234,56' o '1,234.56' o '1.234,56' (o '001234.5600', etc.). Por eso generalmente es una mala idea hacerlo en SQL. Es mejor hacerlo en un programa, que sabe que formato al usuario prefiere.
Pero para mostrarlo, aquí convierto los numeros al formato predeterminado en el base de datos por numeros en los Estados Unidos:
select 
  cic,
  coalesce(format(avg(case when row_num between 1 and  3 then saldo end), 'N', 'en-us'), 'NOTHING') as nro3meses,
  coalesce(format(avg(case when row_num between 1 and  6 then saldo end), 'N', 'en-us'), 'NOTHING') as nro6meses,
  coalesce(format(avg(case when row_num between 1 and 12 then saldo end), 'N', 'en-us'), 'NOTHING') as nro12meses
from #tblsaldo2
group by cic
order by cic;

Documentación de FORMAT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql
Bueno, así que esto no se trata de los últimos meses (2024-04, 2024-03, 2024-02), sino los últimos ventas (meses / fechas) de un cic (¿un articulo?), siempre hay datos para sus últimos tres y seis meses. Si un cic solamente tiene una fila en la tabla es una venta entre los tres meses hasta esta fecha, y también una venta entre los seis meses hasta la fecha, etc. Nunca hy null, nunca hay 'NOTHING'. Entonces, mi consulta muestra como convertir null en 'NOTHING', pero no funciona con tu row_num.
